How to use a recursive variadic tuple as a function parameter type
I have a contrived recursive tuple definition:
type TupleRecursion<T> =
  T extends [infer HEAD, ...infer TAIL]
    ? [HEAD, ...TupleRecursion<TAIL>]
    : [];

and then I try to constrain my function's parameters using this type. I would expect such a function to allow any tuple:
function foo<T>(tuple: TupleRecursion<T>) {}

However, when I call the function with a tuple with two elements:
test(["test", "hi"]);

I get the error "Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 0".
Why is this happening? How can I get TS to accept a tuple of any length and correctly infer its type?
If it matters why I'm doing this, it's because I really want TupleRecursion<T> to constrain the tuple further (specifically, enforce that each element in the tuple satisfies a mapping from the previous element).

It's happening because TS is trying to infer T via reverse mapping, and it's getting the length wrong. The simplest approach to getting in the way of that is usually T & TupleRecursion<T>, or if the use case requires something else,  you could try T extends TupleRecursion<T> ? T : TupleRecursion<T>; both are shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

type ConvertRecursiveTuple<T> = T extends [infer One, ...infer Rest] 
 ? Rest extends []
   ? [One]
   : [One, ...ConvertRecursiveTuple<Rest>]
 : [];

function foo<T extends any[]>(tuple: T & ConvertRecursiveTuple<T>) {
  return tuple;
}
  
const a = foo(["hello", 123, false]);  


You can modify your TupleRecursion type to handle the base case where T is an empty tuple. Here's an updated version of the TupleRecursion type:
    type TupleRecursion<T> =
  T extends [infer HEAD, ...infer TAIL]
    ? [HEAD, ...TupleRecursion<TAIL>]
    : T extends []
      ? []
      : never;

You can then define your foo function as follows using the updated TupleRecursion type:
function foo<T extends any[]>(tuple: TupleRecursion<T>) {
  // Your function implementation here
}


Hmm I still can't get it to work...am I missing something? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAShAxnATgZwJYD2AdgDwwB8UAvAFBSxQQAewERAJjlANp5EBmELFAASAUQCCAEQA0UAHSK+g4TAkBJADIBdOvSgB+HuOlzF8+ElQZs+YmQ2byu-VABcDZqw5duL14Y8-q4eRBAAbkIA3DQ0-HBE6MCERFD8BARkjCxsnFAAhkQgfuQAFMAIyB6WyGiYuClk5ACUUADeAL6x6QSl3ABErDjA-XL9ABZ4-drNUUA
